# Использование рекурсивных отношений в диаграмме классов

Tags: java, классы, uml

Преподаватель обратил внимание, что отношение, когда от пользователя наследуются два связанных пользователя (например, ученик и родитель) образуется кольцо и следует использовать рекурсивную связь
Я не смог найти много информации или примеров касательно этого.
Вот единственное,что везде пишут

> рефлексивные отношения, которые иногда называют рекурсивными отношениями. Обратите внимание на то, что такое отношение всегда необязательно; в противном случае оно было бы по определению бесконечной иерархией. Это правило мы рассмотрим ниже, когда начнем изучать недопустимые и нереализуемые структуры данных.

Возможно, кто-то может пояснить на примерах, как использовать рекурсивную связь и как изменить диаграмму под неё.

Answer (score 1):

Не силен в диаграммах, на уровне классов очевидно имеется ввиду отношение типа:

```
class User {
    int id;
    User parent;
    Type type; //в это поле можно запихать например ваши staff/admin
}

enum Type {
   USER, PUPIL, STAFF, ADMIN
}
```

Где класс ссылается сам на себя.

То есть если поле `parent=null` - то это родитель, а если не `null` - значит это ученик.